# First ajax request not succeeding in Chrome, working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, iframe

Here is what i am doing.

I have a webpage(with SSL). Call it s1.

It hosts a `.js` file, which installs a 3rd-party js, used to navigate it. (say s2)

On a click on an element, it loads an iframe(another website, say s2), which in turn passes data to my js hosted on s1.

This is working correctly in IE, Firefox etc, but in Chrome, the first such instance gets cancelled.

**When i try again (*after the first request is cancelled*), it works as expected.** (after the first cancellation).

Any ideas on what might be happening. Am not sure how to post a working snippet here as the second iframe is a protected one.

I am guessing something to do with Cross-domain communication, but not sure as it's working in other browsers.

Any ideas on what could be happening.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code, html and javascript

Comment: Try to run a trace tool (like Fiddler) and see what is going over the wire. Might give you some more insight,

Comment: The code is restricted, i am afraid, so am finding ways to post a working snippet of the problem. Tried fiddler, gives nothing in POST.